Very poor docker build / compiling performance, 100% cpu by kworker/u48:3+flush-8:64
I recently found that my system was really slow when compiling large amount of code or more specifically when doing a docker compose build. When comparing with a college, the execution time of the same docker compose build was 1752s vs 45s on his machine (comparable specs).
I noticed a process I am not familiar with that is running at 100% of it's thread when the compilation seems to struggle :  kworker/u48:3+flush-8:64

Here is some info about my install :
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"

Disk /dev/sde: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: Portable SSD T5 
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A27DE861-2F2B-4B02-BE02-963A5359D843

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1   65535     983024     917490  448M EFI System
/dev/sde2  983025 1953467279 1952484255  931G Linux filesystem


I installed Kubuntu 22.04.4 on an external SSD and use it as my main OS on different computers, it worked flawlessly for more than two years but it has become nearly unusable when dealing with big compilation or docker builds. I am kind of lost because of the lack of information about this issue and I cannot find the true cause of it.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Have you tried turning it on and off again ?

I found out about a thread discussing a similar issue : New: ext4(?) regression since 6.5.0
This issue seemed to be related to stripe and ext4. I checked my fs with mount and got ext4(rw,.....,stripe=8191). In the thread, they mentioned the following command : tune2fs -f -E stripe_width=0 <dev>. I applied this and after a reboot, performance seems normal again. I am not 100% sure if removing this variable (which I did not add myself) is a good idea or not, but the result seems to be working.
If I see any errors I will edit this post in the future.
